# Unable to view designer in VS2010 due to DLL over the network

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, xaml

I am getting the error -

Unable to load the metadata for assembly 'Aurora.UIResources'. This assembly may have been downloaded from the web.  See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=179545.  The following error was encountered during load: Could not load file or assembly 'Aurora.UIResources, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. Operation is not supported. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131515)

I am referencing the file over the network and the application will run and work just fine. I just can't seem to see the 'preview' in the designer. I am running Windows 7 Enterprise 64bit.

Does anyone have an idea on how to resolve this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

See [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/setupprerelease/thread/3b6bda91-e085-4b9d-b2f1-61f1d4aa2c51)

This seems to work for some people

"Open devenv.exe.config (in C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE on my machine), and add this"

```
<runtime>
    <loadFromRemoteSources enabled="true" />
    ....
</runtime>
```

Comment: There isn't an unblock option.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the part about the network, thought it was local.