# Unable to load the metadata for assembly

Tags: .net, wpf, visual-studio-2010, networking

I'm having a problem with a project in Visual Studio 2010 after moving to a new corporate issued Windows 7 machine (from an aging XP machine).

I copied my projects across to the new machine, but Visual Studio seems to be having problems loading the WPF designer. I have a solution that includes several projects, it builds fine and runs fine, but when I try to open a WPF window in the designer, I get a whole bunch of error messages along the lines of:

```
"unable to load the metadata for assembly 'Foo'. This assembly may have been 
downloaded from the web.  See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=179545.  
The following error was encountered during load: Could not load file or assembly
'Foo, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its 
dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."
```

(Note the link in the error message seems to be no use whatsoever)

I think the problem here is that my corporate IT people have set up Windows 7 machines such that "My Documents" is actually a network drive that is cached locally. This is not a bad thing, because now all my files are backed up whenever I'm on the corporate network, but I think it's upsetting Visual Studio.

Is there a solution to this that doesn't involve abandoning the synched network drive (which I like) and copying everything to the local hard drive (which puts backups back on me).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The  solution found here on stackoverflow:

[Unable to view designer in VS2010 due to DLL over the network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4099028/unable-to-view-designer-in-vs2010-due-to-dll-over-the-network?rq=1)

> This seems to work for some people
>
> "Open devenv.exe.config (in C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   10.0\Common7\IDE on my machine), and add this"
>
> ```
> <runtime>
>     <loadFromRemoteSources enabled="true" />
> </runtime>
> ```

worked for me. Same problem working in corporate environment, instead of on my own machine.

Comment: Thanks. I think that was the problem. Or at least it got rid of those errors, but now I'm having all kinds of other problems with they way they've set up my sync!

Comment: If you can't find it at `C:\Program Files\...`, try `C:\Program Files (x86)...`.

Answer (score 1):

Check if you some reference to dll installed on the local drive of the old XP machine.
E.g. reference to a dll installed only on the GAC of the old machine!!

The process of locating and binding to an assembly is described here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yx7xezcf(v=vs.100).aspx

I suggest you:

1. To check GAC (**but your comment seems to discard this**)
2. To look for Codebase tags in configuration files
3. To read this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/15hyw9x3.aspx

Comment: I don't *think* that's the problem. All the project that it's complaining about are part of the same solution. They were never installed in the GAC and have only been used with an xcopy deployment.

Comment: Please, see my new answer and let me know!

Comment: Thanks for you help, but I don't think that's the problem. It's *only* the WPF designer that seems to be having a problem with this. Otherwise everything builds and runs just fine. Either way, I'm having all kinds of problems with this sync folder right now that I'm trying to get my sysadmins to fix. So I can't quite be sure where the problem is coming from right now.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue when my assembly was neither on network nor on shared drive nor was it downloaded from internet. I realized the issue was due to a long folder path in which the assembly was residing.

I had a path which was 120 characters long. I reduced my assembly path to 30 characters (and removed some dots in folder names) and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

It's worth mentioning that you'll also get this error if you clean your solution for whatever reason. The next time you build, it should be fixed in this scenario.