# Winforms-Designer is not working with references to libraries located in local network

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2012, assembly-references

i am using Visual Studio 2012 and in my c#-project i have some references to DLLs located on another machine in the local network. At the beginning everything worked fine and it still compiles without any problem.

But now the Forms-Designer does not work and it tells me, that it can't find this references.

For a short period the usage of a network drive solved this problem, but now i get the same errors.
I hope anyone has an idea how to solve this issue...

Before you answer this question keep in mind, that copying the libraries to my local drive is not an option.

Comment: Solution can be found in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4099028/unable-to-view-designer-in-vs2010-due-to-dll-over-the-network).

Answer (score 0):

What error message do you get?
Reasons as to why references would fail include:

1. The project's reference path is incorrect or incomplete.
2. The file being referenced has been deleted.
3. The file being referenced has been renamed.
4. The network connection or authentication has failed.

I had this problem before where we referenced dlls from a network share and the problem was after a period of time the share permissions changing without anyone knowing!

Comment: file or assembly or one of its dependencies was not found. Its only in the designer, compiling works fine.

Comment: Do i need to have write permissions on that folder? On another machine it works.

Comment: I guess your references have an exclamation mark next to them? Remove and re add to see if it works. Another thing to try is to disable UAC/run as administrator. Just need read permissions on the network share.

Comment: No there is no exclamation mark. As i said, it can compile and run. Its only the design mode where this happens. I tried everything of your options and i have read permissions, but no success.

Comment: See if this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4099028/unable-to-view-designer-in-vs2010-due-to-dll-over-the-network

Comment: This and adding full trust to the directory did it.